# ASP.Net Core Razor Page submit button going to /Home/Post

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 site that we recently upgraded to ASP.Net Core 3.1. Had a few problems with API URLs and Controller URLs that we have resolved.

One problem that has just come up is that we have a Razor page with a submit button on it that is going directly to /Home/Post instead of posting to itself (in this case /Admin/GenerateIds).

Here's the button on the csthml page at /Admin/GenerateIds.csthml:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-action" type="submit">Generate Ids</button>
```

And the form that the button is in:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="POST">
```

In ASP.Net Core 2.1, this worked. In Core 3.1, the URL loaded when the button is clicked is /Home/Post

TIA,
Owen

Answer (score 0):

Answer: the asp-action="POST" was causing the Razor page (in core 3.1, but not in core 2.1) to go to the action handler defined (by convention) at /Home/Handler-name where, in this case, we were specifying "Post" as the handler name.

Removing the asp-action="POST" from the form tag resolved the issue: the page now posts back to itself as desired.

--Owen